# displaying text data - interactive in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, dashboard, interactive

I am using the seanmf topic modelling code in Python. This basically uses machine learning to divide large text data into groups. I have the number of categories (x) and number of keywords (y) in each category. I'd like to build some sort of interactive dashboard (ideally using Jupyter notebook) where a user can select the category and the number of keywords (i.e., x and y) and the dashboard would display all the relevant keywords in that category. So, if I select category 5 and 10 keywords, it will print the 10 keywords in category 5. I have this dataset ready but don't know how to proceed and build such a dashboard. Any ideas would be great!

The txt data looks like this:

```
Topic 14: products services workpieces finished promote decorative customer attach finishes inventories 
Topic 7: information gather public record interview provide present customers news explain 
Topic 6: prepare reports documents technical use operational applications budgets contracts solutions
```

This is a data extract where x is 25 (so there are 25 topics) and y is 10. That's why for each topic you can see 10 keywords.

Comment: You say you have the dataset ready; could you show a part of it, an example to give us an idea of the data / data structure that you work with?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the post.